# inserting values into multiple tables using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

i have existing tables **hotel** and **hotel_services**.

```
hotel table contains:
hotel_id
hotel_name

hotel_services contains:
hotel_id
hotel_service_name
```

each hotel can offer several services, so in my form user could enter as many services as he wants at a time.

so for instance:

```
hotel name: HOTEL1
hotel_services:
1. hotel_service1
2. hotel_service2
3. hotel_service3
```

My question is how should i do it in hibernate in such a way that i'll be able to insert all the data into their respective tables(which are hotels and hotel_services tables).

thanks for the help..

Comment: this is very basic ORM mapping, read some tutorials

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're describing is a basic `OneToMany` relation between an `Hotel` and `Services` and the mapping would look like this (I'll map it as a bidirectional association, using annotations):

```
@Entity
public class Hotel {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="hotel")
    Set<Service> services = new HashSet<Service>();

    // other attributes, getters, setters

    // method to manage the bidirectional association
    public void addToServices(Service service) {
        this.services.add(service);
        service.setHotel(this);
}

@Entity
public class Service {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Hotel hotel;

    // getters, setters, equals, hashCode
}
```

And here is a snippet demonstrating how to use this:

```
SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(); // this is a custom utility class
Session session = sf.openSession(); 
session.beginTransaction();

Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
Service s1 = new Service();
Service s2 = new Service();
hotel.addToServices(s1);
hotel.addToServices(s2);
session.persist(hotel);

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

To go further (because I won't explain everything in this answer), have a look at:

- [Hibernate Getting Started Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html_single/index.html) (covers the Native API with XML mappings, the Native API with annotations, the JPA API)
- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [Chapter 1. Tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html)