# How to save two related objects to data base with relation OneToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I'm trying to save an U object I got next exception:

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.roc.domain.A.user]; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.roc.domain.A.user]

I have two tables: 
 1. user that columns are id(auto incr, primary), name.
 2. contact that columns are id, user_id(that is foreign key -> user.id) and address.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="address")
  private String address;

  @OneToOne
  @MapsId
  private U user;

  public A() {

  }
   // getters and setters



}


@Entity
@Table(name = "u")
public class U {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;
  @Column(name="username")
  private String userName;
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private A a;

  public U(){};

}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTest {

  @Autowired
  private URepository uRepository;

  @Test
  public void simpleCrudTest() {
    U user = new U("name", new A("address"));
    uRepository.save(user);


  }
}
```

Comment: can you add the Table relationship structure in the question.You entity kind of wrong I think.(Not sure) so add the table relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the cascade correctly however because the relationship is bi-directional you need to set both sides in the in-memory model.

```
  @Test
  public void simpleCrudTest() {
    U user = new U("name", new A("address"));

   //will work when this is added 
   a.setUser(user);
   uRepository.save(user);

  }
```

Otherwise, as the error states, A has a null reference for user on save.

Comment: But if I need uni-directional relationship? What I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: To save using a single repository save call.**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private U user;

    public A() {

    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "u")
public class U {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private A a;

    public U() {
    };

    // method to manage the bidirectional association
    public U addToA(A a) {
        this.a.add(a);
        a.setUser(this);

    }

}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private URepository uRepository;

    @Test
    public void simpleCrudTest() {

        U user = new U();
        user.addToA(new A("address"));

        user.setUserName("username");
        uRepository.save(user);

    }
}
```

Also, you refer to this link.

[inserting values into multiple tables using hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921806/inserting-values-into-multiple-tables-using-hibernate)

```
      You have to save A first, Then set saved A to U and save U.    


        @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
            @SpringBootTest
            public class ApplicationTest {

              @Autowired
              private URepository uRepository;

              @Autowired
              private ARepository aRepository;

              @Test
              @Trascational
              public void simpleCrudTest() {

                A a = new A();
                a.setAddress("address");
                a = aRepository.save(a);

                U user = new U("name", a);
                uRepository.save(user);


              }
            }
```

Comment: Yes it's an option. But is it possible to save in one line? probably ORM can do it some how?)

Comment: To make that happen you need to change your entity. Use a Secondary table. refer this link https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-how-to-map-an-entity-to-multiple-tables/