# How to save parent-child entities with @OneToOne mapping and sequence generated based on primary key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I've been getting nowhere after spending hours on this.  I can't get around this error from the database:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "receiver_params" violates foreign key constraint "fkoo8xfchpie8h1lock8ish68a7"
  Detail: Key (id)=(46) is not present in table "partner".
```

**Attempt:**

I'm trying to save a Partner like so:

```
Partner partner = new Partner();
ReceiverParams params = new ReceiverParams();
partner.setReceiverParams(params);
partnerDao.save(partner);
```

**Code:**

Here are the relevant bits of the Entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class Partner {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize= 1, name = "catalogGen", sequenceName = "catalogCounter")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "catalogGen")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="partner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ReceiverParams receiverParams;
}

@Entity
public class ReceiverParams {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize= 1, name = "catalogGen", sequenceName = "catalogCounter")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "catalogGen")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Partner partner;
}
```

And the table DDL:

```
-- Table: partner
CREATE TABLE partner
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT partner_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fko7mdrugj20xnulw9nph9hw34x FOREIGN KEY (sender_config_id)
        REFERENCES config (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fksypxt08sx9qj5vma73dvlawoa FOREIGN KEY (receiver_config_id)
        REFERENCES config (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;


-- Table: receiver_params
CREATE TABLE receiver_params
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT receiver_params_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fkoo8xfchpie8h1lock8ish68a7 FOREIGN KEY (id)
        REFERENCES partner (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

I've tried saving the 'partner' then adding the 'params', saving the params first, then partner.  But I can't figure out how to save the partner with the params linked.

From reading other code, I'm pretty confident the annotations on the model classes are correct.  The SQL was auto-generated.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

FWIW, this is my PartnerDao:

```
public interface PartnerDao extends JpaRepository<Partner, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save two related objects to data base with relation OneToOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56845677/how-to-save-two-related-objects-to-data-base-with-relation-onetoone)

Comment: If you are using shared PK model then you should also remove `@ID` and associated annotations form dependent class. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships

Comment: The issue ended up being the Generator on the ReceiverParams ID field.  I needed to use a foreign key strategy for the 'partners' property.  See answer below

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my `ReceiverParams` class was generating a new ID instead of using the foreign key strategy to use the ID on the related `Partner` class.

Here's the part that changed on `ReceiverParams`.  Specifically the `@GenericGenerator` annotation with `foreign` strategy applied to property `partner`.

```
@Entity
public class ReceiverParams {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "receiverGen", strategy = "foreign", parameters = { @Parameter(name = "property", value = "partner") })
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "receiverGen")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

// ... the rest was unchanged in all remaining files

}
```

Comment: Setting both sides of the association as noted below and using standard JPA mappings for dependent PK would be a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

You have bidirectional releationship and I think that you are not setting both sides of it correctly.

Try this:

```
Partner partner = new Partner();
ReceiverParams params = new ReceiverParams();

partner.setReceiverParams(params);
params.setPartner(partner);

partnerDao.save(partner);
```

More elegant way to achieve the same result with modification of `setReceiverParams` method:

```
public void setReceiverParams(ReceiverParams params) {
     params.setPartner(this);
     this.params = params;
}
```